# jena Result in Html(servlets/jsp)

Tags: java, servlets, jena

```
List<RowObject> results = new ArrayList<RowObject>();
```

I tried the above code from [Print the jena result set in html(servlet/jsp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985233/print-the-jena-result-set-in-htmlservlet-jsp) post
and got the following error:

> RowObject cannot be resolved to a type

I also want to do exactly same as given in the post. Is `RowObject` a userdefined class ?
If yes,then how to I build it? I am confused regarding this `RowObject` thing.

Comment: Please don't remove the original question and reuse the question for something entirely different. It makes existing answers pointless and confusing. Press `Ask Question` button on top to ask new questions. I've rolled back the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a [Javabean class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727603/places-where-javabeans-are-used). The classname doesn't matter, as long as it represents its content. And yes, you need to create it yourself.

Comment: results.nextSolution(); //works fine .                                                                 while, result.nextSolution() ; gives and error.please tell what to define in the nextSolution method                                                          IS results.nextSolution() correct as results is of type ResultSet